# Display XChat icon in message menu

Tags: xchat

I’m pretty sure this is possible since I had it that way before my fresh install. Now installed XChat and it’s icon is shown on the panel. How can I move it to the message menu?

Comment: Can you give us some details, like are you running Unity in 11.04, or are you running GNOME2/Ubuntu classic?

Comment: yes 11.04 classic the Ken van Dine works. I guess I still have to black list so it won’t display on the panel

Comment: Here's a duplicate of this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/92150/how-to-hide-xchat-icon-from-panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go Ken Van Dine did it:
http://blogs.gnome.org/kenvandine/2010/01/12/xchat-indicator/

Comment: Can you edit your answer to avoid [linkrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) please?