# How to hide xchat icon from panel?

Tags: xchat

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and i have installed xchat. How do i hide xchat icon from my panel? Please find the attached screenshot for the reference.[image]

Comment: I am using ubuntu classic desktop, not Unity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just noticed you are using the Classic mode of Natty - to hide the tray icon you need to delve into X-Chat's preferences

[image]